# randomness numbers using loop while to draw numbers 21

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, draw

Using a While loop to create a script that will randomly draw numbers from 0 to 100. Until the draw of number 21. I want a draw number 21 using loop while.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to keep the loop running until the number is equal to 21.
So in the condition for the while-loop you have to check if the number is not equal to 21, then regenerate a random number. If the number is equal to 21 it will jump out of the loop and in this case display the number which is obviously 21.

```
   $number = -1;
   while ($number != 21) {
       $number = rand(0, 100);
   }
   echo $number;
```

Comment: I think you may want the echo inside the loop. Otherwise this is functionally equivalent to just doing `echo 21`, without a loop.